# How can i make an mysql id appear on a link?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I mean, I'm trying the web link to look like `something.com/newpage.php?id=123...`.

What I have is a form, and a JavaScript function on load that runs this AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "postear.php",
    data: "addcontentbox=" + addcontent,
    success: function() {
        $("ul#wall").prepend("<li><a href='newpage.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>'  target='_blank'>"+addcontent+"</a></li>");
        $("ul#wall li:first").fadeIn();
        document.postbar_add_post.addcontent.value='';
        $('form#postbar_add_post input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

and this is the PHP function that is calls on the url:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['addcontent'])) 
{
    // Connection to Database
    include('config.php');

    // No Query Injection
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addcontent']);

    // echo
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test.wall (message) VALUES("' . $message . '")';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo $message;
}
else
{
    echo '0';
}
?>
```

also, tried to place there a _GET [id].. but nothing.

Any help ?

pd:the dabase is:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`wall` (
`id` INT( 6 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`message` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENG
```

Comment: Do you know if the PHP is actually called by the AJAX function. You might have syntax errors somewhere, or it might be the wrong URL. Also, check your JavaScript console - I went to edit your question and you've left off the closing `});` for the AJAX call. A typo, maybe.

Comment: oh, thanks.   Yes, maybe i missed that closing }); when pasting here, but yes, I see it on my document.    Thanksss!

Comment: Actually, you missed two, but I digress. No problem - editing posts means higher quality questions, which means higher quality answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first u need to change this lines

```
success: function() {
$("ul#wall").prepend("<li><a href='newpage.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>'  target='_blank'>"+addcontent+"</a></li>");
```

to

```
success: function(data) {
$("ul#wall").prepend("<li><a href='newpage.php?id="+data+"    target='_blank'>"+addcontent+"</a></li>");
```

and in the php file instead of this three lines

```
   $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo $message;
```

u should write

```
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

of course you have to set the id fild in the database to autoincrement first

it doesn't hurt to change this

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test.wall (message) VALUES("' . $message . '")';
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test.wall (`message`) VALUES('$message')";
```

i mean it's easier this way

Comment: wow thanks!  as soon as changed to echo mysql_insert_id  it worked!!! =D . THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need a call to mysql_insert_id instead of mysql_fetch_array. i.e. You haven't pulled back the autoincrement ID from mysql (and that's making the assumption your wall table has an autoincrement primary key..?)

Comment: I trieddd, but still nothingg >.<.     Im double checking every now to see if its a typo or syntax error, but so far, i hvant find whats wrongg. >.<.     Thanks.